# How can we achieve large font accessibility in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, accessibility, font-size, large-text

My application is developed using Xamarin.iOS and I need to make it accessible. We couldn't find any help to achieve large text accessibility in xamarin.iOS. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066791/how-do-i-support-accessibility-font-sizes-in-xamarin-forms) link which explains how to achieve it in Xamarin.Forms and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41794/how-can-i-access-text-size-in-display-brightness-and-ios-accessibility-settings) about MonoTouch. Could someone help me how to achieve Large text accessibility on Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Support Accessibility Font Sizes in Xamarin Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066791/how-do-i-support-accessibility-font-sizes-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Assign one of the `UIFontTextStyle`s to your UI elements and when the app starts the element's text size will be set based upon the `UIFontTextStyle` and the user's current `Accessibility Larger Text` setting:

```
var uiLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect(40, 40, 200, 40));
uiLabel.Text = "StackOverflow";
uiLabel.Font = UIFont.GetPreferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Body);
View.AddSubview(uiLabel);
```

If you want to dynamically response to the `Accessibility Larger Text`  changes so the user does not have to restart your app, subscribe to `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` and update your views:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
    new NSString("UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification"),
    (NSNotification obj) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update layouts/subviews/layers/etc...");
        View.SetNeedsLayout();
    },
    null
);
```

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, but how can we apply the specific font size that is given in redlines and make it work with large text setting.

Comment: @NarenderReddy The real question is have your designers included `Dynamic Type` considerations in your Redline document? And what font sizes your UI is going to support (and not support) in terms of dynamic type sizes as changing the font size can cause the entire UI to reflow based on its constaints. Not all apps support dynamic accessibility font sizes nor do they need too..., that is up to your app requirements and should be stated in your redline documents/wireframes/mockapps

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover. My situation is, the app is developed without accessibility first and now we need to make it accessible so, there are no redlines as such now. But, I wonder if there is any chance that the large font accessibility can be enabled on top of the specific font size that is already applied.

Comment: @NarenderReddy Sure it can, you can assign font size multipliers for your font for how it should scale (up & down) based upon the user's currently selected accessibility size compared to your standard baseline font sizes (i.e. when Large Fonts is turned off in Settings). So if a UI element should be track based upon the point size of `UIFontTextStyle.Body`, then get the large font `Body`'s current point size (`UIFontDescriptor.PreferredBody.PointSize`) multiple it by your scale and create/assign a `UIFont` using `FromDescriptor` to your UI element.

Comment: @NarenderReddy *One* of the ways that I handle it is to create a Dictionary of Dictionaries for my fonts at app startup, one element for each different font, within that one `UIFont` that is created to match each the different `UIFontTextStyle.XXX` current font size assigned from `Setting's Large Fonts`...... `UIFontDescriptor.PreferredBody.PointSize`, `UIFontDescriptor.PreferredHeadline.PointSize`, `UIFontDescriptor.PreferredSubheadline.PointSize`, etc....

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover. Sorry to piggyback on this post. But I have a question. Im using label renderer for my labels and I want to also be able to have my label dynamically change depending on the iphone settings without having to restart the application. May I know where should I put the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` ? Sorry if the question is very silly.

Answer (score 0):

MonoTouch and Xamarin.iOS are the same thing, just a different name.

It is achieved in the exact same way, where you set the `Font` property of your `UILabel` or `UITextField` to one of the available fonts in the `UIFont` static class like so:

```
var label = new UILabel
{
    Font = UIFont.PreferredBody
};
```

This should automatically scale the fonts according to your Accessibility settings on iOS.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron for your reply. If we want to give specific font size that is according to the redlines shared by the designer, can this still achievable ?