# How to get the accessibility font size for iOS and Android in Xamarin.Forms so I can change font-size in a HTML WebView?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, xamarin

I am trying to allow the HTML font-size in a Xamarin.Forms WebView to increase/decrease in size according to the user's accessibility Large Text settings.

I want to do the following:

1: Get the preferred font size for text options (title, body, caption, etc.) from the Accessibility Large Text options for iOS and Android.

2: Get the default size for some HTML text (h1 could be 15px, h2 could be 13px, h3 could be 11px, p could be 7px, etc.) and use that with the correct text option (h1 <-> title, p <-> body) to calculate the new font-size for that HTML element.

I have found some links for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066791/how-do-i-support-accessibility-font-sizes-in-xamarin-forms/), [Android/iOS](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43575/getting-android-ios-accessibility-font-sizes) and [Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Font_Size) on how to get some font-sizes but I can not figure out how I would get these sizes, translate the sizes of these text options to the size of some default HTML elements (H1,H2, P) and do the math to calculate the new font-size for the CSS.

Can someone help me out by figuring out some sort of plan on how I would do this? Or can someone help me by giving me a link on how I can get some sort of percentage on how big a font-size is compared to a certain default value thanks to Accessibility large text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured it out:

Android changes the HTML text size according to the accessibility settings automatically. No work required!

iOS allows a developer to implement several CSS classes to make the WebView change 
it's text size to the accessibility settings on the iOS device.[Click here to find out more](http://www.interactiveaccessibility.com/blog/text-resizing-web-pages-ios-using-dynamic-type)

These are the classes:

`-apple-system-headline
-apple-system-subheadline
-apple-system-short-headline
-apple-system-short-subheadline
-apple-system-body
-apple-system-short-body
-apple-system-tall-body
-apple-system-caption1
-apple-system-caption2
-apple-system-short-caption1
-apple-system-footnote
-apple-system-short-footnote`

[Go to this website on your iOS device to see what the classes look like](https://thepaciellogroup.github.io/IA-Coding-Patterns/iOS/text-resizing/ios-system-fonts.html)

To use Apple's predefined fonts:`p {font: -apple-system-body}`

To use your own font: (You can also create your own font-family with `@font-face` and reference that instead of Arial!)

```
p {
    font: -apple-system-body;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

You can use the following properties:

```
font-family
font-weight
font-style
font-variant`
```

To use your own font-size:

```
p {
  font: -apple-system-body;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.body-text-size {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
<p><span class="body-text-size>This is some text in my page.</span></p>
```

Hope it helps!

*Update 04-2020*: I noticed one of my preview links was dead. I fixed it by finding another repo that hosted the file. I have linked that one instead and in case my links die again, I have added them to the web archive so you can find them there! :)

Comment: The answers seems correct but a little confused on the terminology. These are not *classes*, but predefined platform specific values for the css `font` shorthand property.