# For Accessibility: How to achieve a consistent and scalable font size across browsers?

Tags: html, css, less, accessibility, font-size

## Goal

My goal is to make our WebApp more accessible to dynamic font sizes. Especially for accessibility reasons, where people set bigger font sizes.

## Context / Progress so far:

The WebApp is used on desktop and within our native Apps as a WebView. Our target audience uses mainly:

- Safari desktop browser
- Chrome desktop browser
- Safari on mobile devices (iOS) as a WebView
- Chrome on mobile devices (Android) as a WebView

So far I found out, that the 'normal' way to do this, is by setting `font-size: 100%` on root/html level and then reference it via `rem` (or through `em` but that sounds a bit hard to maintain on a multi level architecture).

The problem is, that this does not work for the Safari WebView case. Here it seems necessary to read a special variable, which I found on this Thread: [How to get the accessibility font size for iOS and Android in Xamarin.Forms so I can change font-size in a HTML WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955105/how-to-get-the-accessibility-font-size-for-ios-and-android-in-xamarin-forms-so-i)

Now it really starts to get interesting, because using this value gives different values depending on is it Safari Desktop or Safari WebView, while Chrome of course does not know this value and uses its 'normal' 100% value. Here is a list of what I debugged, using normal font sizes:

- Chrome: `16px`
- Safari Desktop: `13px` (with `-apple-system-body`)
- Safari WebView: `17px` (with `-apple-system-body`)

### The Problem

My goal is to have one consistent UI across the browsers, so if I would just use those values combined with `rem` I would get a way smaller text size on Safari than on Chrome for example.

## My main question is:

Is there a more elegant way to solve the dynamic font size issue, while keeping a consistent UI across browsers? Or is there an elegant CSS / LESS solution towards unifying the above values to one value, while keeping it reactive to system font settings?

### Not desired solution:

The only solutions I can think of, would be reading out those values with javascript, detecting the browser, normalising it accordingly and setting it back. But I would like to avoid that solution, because it seems quite unstable to me, especially if maybe at some point Apple updates Safari to use different standard font sizes.

Comment: Have you tried simply **not setting font-size at all** for the root level? This is an approach I’ve been using for 20 years now, which simply respects the users’ and the platform’s default font size. Of course, you still can reference `rem` without explicitly setting a base font size

Comment: Just tested that and it does not work for the Safari WebView case. Increasing the font size on an iPhone will have no effect then.

Comment: Well if Safari is not respecting the system font size setting even if you don’t specify any size, I’m afraid it might simply not be possible on that platform.

Comment: It is possible by reading a Safari specific variable, for example this one: -apple-system-body. See also the other linked StackOverflow issue in my question description. But the core issue with it is, that it starts with another base value as Chrome or even between Safari desktop and WebView.