# How to make `Label`'s font size inside `ViewCell` dependent on the device in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

So I have a few custom cells using `ViewCell` in my app. Inside my `ViewCell` are `Labels`. I want the font size of those labels to be dependent on the text size of the device just like how the `TextCell`'s text changes when you adjust the text size of your device.

Below image is using a built-in `TextCell`.
[image]

Below image is using a custom cell `ViewCell`
[image]

Im testing this in an iOS device and the text size is set to the smallest available. Whenever I change the device text size the cells using `TextCell`s will just automatically changed. The labels inside the `ViewCell` doesn't change at all. Any suggestion pointing me to the right direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066791/how-do-i-support-accessibility-font-sizes-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

The `TextCell` uses the native `UITableViewCell` on iOS. This native view takes the device accessibility settings into account. When you use the Xamarin Forms `Label`, it does not. Xamarin Forms does not support iOS Dynamic Type (yet).

**Explanation**

The Forms `Label` uses the `FontSizeConverter` to set the actual font size. This font size [defaults to the value `-1`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5f2796e160f99bad31c1b06a2d1f328b5ed02ba3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FontElement.cs#L15) if you don't set any value yourself. The value `-1` results in the use of `NamedSize.Default` (see [the Font class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5f2796e160f99bad31c1b06a2d1f328b5ed02ba3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Font.cs#L21)).

When you take a look at the [`FontSizeConverter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5f2796e160f99bad31c1b06a2d1f328b5ed02ba3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FontSizeConverter.cs), if it can't parse the value as an absolute value, it will try to convert to a `NamedSize` value. In that case, it will use `Device.GetNamedSize` to get the actual size. This is done through the `IPlatformServices` interface, which converts these to absolute values ([see the `IOSPlatformServices`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6d5186c8acbf37b877c7ca3c77a378352a3743d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Forms.cs#L192)).

There is also a `FontExtensions` class, that implements the same conversion from Named Size to an absolute value. Not very DRY at first sight, but there could be a good reason for this, that I'm not aware of.

Unfortunately, both the `FontExtensions` and the `IOSPlatformServices` don't take the accessibility options of iOS into account, but just return absolute values.

**Possible solution**

On iOS, you could use  `UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.PreferredContentSizeCategory` to get the current accessibility category. Based on this value, you could determine a scale for your fonts (use `DynamicResource` for the font sizes if you use them in XAML, so they can change at runtime).

Or take a look at [SushiHangover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38070534/6192895) on a similar question.

See [the `preferredContentSizeCategory` on the Apple Developer API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623048-preferredcontentsizecategory).

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will check the above link.