# Do the UI elements in Xamarin scale automatically?

Tags: xamarin

Do the UI elements in Xamarin scale automatically with different screen resolutions or do I have to do something?

Comment: possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066791/how-do-i-support-accessibility-font-sizes-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what type of project you use and how you make your UI.

If you are using Xamarin.Forms you can set height and width requests, that should scale with resolution.

If you are using classic Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects, each of the underlying platforms have ways to scale views on different screen sizes. Most of the time, if you are not using fixed widths and heights views should scale fine.

In both cases, make sure to provide correctly sized image assets for icons etc.

Comment: Is it possible to use svg images for the icon and other assets?

Comment: It is possible on Android to convert your SVGs to VectorDrawables. On iOS you need to use pdf's or convert the SVGs at runtime using something like NGraphics or FFImageLoading.

Comment: Seems too much work. Maybe just use high resolution png?

Comment: That can lead to memory issues. Especially on old Android devices with low RAM.

Comment: Ok I am really sorry what do you recommend then?

Comment: I recommend you to use what each platforms give you on how to manage image assets. The views themselves are no problem if you use constraints based layouts or don't set fixed widths and heights. Android allows you to put image assets in hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, mdpi etc folders. iOS allows you to provide images with \@2x, \@3x for icons etc. Use what each platform hands you. This is well documented.